# Trying to pull NBA_API playerlogs and continue to get the following error and unable to pull active player game logs

Tags: python, nba-api

Here is the JSON error I am receiving.

### Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: nba_api in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.1.14)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from nba_api) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0,>=1.22.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from nba_api) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->nba_api) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->nba_api) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->nba_api) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from requests->nba_api) (2.10)

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
9
10 # Get player game logs for the specified date range
---> 11 response = PlayerGameLogs(player_id_nullable=player_id, date_from_nullable=start_date, date_to_nullable=end_date).get_json()
12
13 # Print the response

7 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I was expecting to pull Darius Garland game log data for the period selected.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code snippet that's causing the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.